# getItems(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I call YT API and get this error:

```
var videoResultsFullData = YouTube.Videos.list('id,snippet, contentDetails', { id : searchResults.getItems().map(item => item.id.videoId)})
```

`searchResults.getItems(...).map is not a function`

[image]

[image]

Comment: `items` does not looks like an Array. Could you provide the log of `searchResults.getItems()` ?

Comment: i think `searchResults.getItems()` is not returning an array.

Comment: @SifatHaque I see it returns a string(?) so how can I transform it to a list of ids easily? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjdiQ.png

Comment: @farvilain Is that the log you mean? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjdiQ.png

Comment: @farvilain The log: `earchResults.getItems() =={"snippet":{"thumbnails":{"default":{"width":120,"height":90,"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ebsS9tEi5zc/default.jpg"},"medium":{"height":180,"width":320,"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ebsS9tEi5zc/mqdefault.jpg"},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ebsS9tEi5zc/hqdefault.jpg","width":480,"height":360}},"liveBroadcastContent":"none","title":"Rescue Abandoned Puppies Building Mud House Dog And Fish Pond For Red Fish","description":"Rescue Abandoned Puppies Building Mud House Dog And Fish Pond For Red Fish.`